# Dynamic screens in kivymd

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy, kivymd

I've been working with kivymd for awhile and I wanna create a screen in which it's contents will change depending on content that is clicked for example let's say I have a home screen with products and when each product is clicked another screen will open with the image and details of that specific product and that should be possible for each other product

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 screens for this.

1. `MainScreen` to show all the products
2. `Productscreen` to show details of the product.

You can add the contents on the `screen` according to the product being clicked. This way, you do not need to create a separate `screen` for each product.

**Note**: Since the contents on the `productscreen` will be added at runtime, you will need to write it in `.py` file and not `.kv` file.